# I need help to compute $\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{1}{t\sqrt{t^2 -1}} dt$

Tags: integration

I want to compute $\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{1}{t\sqrt{t^2 -1}} dt$.

I already proved that $\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{1}{t^{\alpha}\sqrt{t^2 -1}} dt$ is finite for any $\alpha >0$ and I tried to compute this specific one by finding a primitive of it or using integration by parts without any success.
Wolfram alpha gives me the result $\frac{\pi}{2}$ but I have no clue how to get that.

Comment: Put $ t = sec$x

Comment: The change of variable $$x=\sqrt{t^2-1}$$ works like a charm, no?

Comment: **Hint :** $$\int_1^\infty\frac1{t~\sqrt{t^2-1}}~dt ~=~ \int_1^\infty\frac{t}{t^2~\sqrt{t^2-1}}~dt ~=~ \int_1^\infty\frac{\tfrac12~d\big(t^2-1\big)}{\Big[\big(t^2-1\big)+1\Big]\sqrt{t^2-1}}$$ Can you take it from here ? ;-$)$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set $u=1/t$ then $du=-1/t^2 dt = -u^2dt$

$$\int \frac u{\sqrt {(1/u)^2-1}}\frac{du}{u^2}=-\int\frac 1{\sqrt{1-u^2}}du=-\arcsin(u)+C=-\arcsin\frac1t+C$$

$$\lim _{t\to \infty} \arcsin (1/t)=\arcsin(0)=0$$
$$\lim _{t\to 1 } \arcsin (1/t)=\arcsin(1)=\frac \pi 2$$
$$\boxed{\color{blue}{\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{1}{t\sqrt{t^2 -1}} dt=\frac \pi 2}}$$

Answer (score 4):

By setting $t=\frac{1}{z}$, then $z=\sqrt{u}$, we have
$$ I(\alpha)=\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{t^\alpha\sqrt{t^2-1}}=\int_{0}^{1}z^{\alpha-1}(1-z^2)^{-1/2}\,dz = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}u^{\frac{\alpha}{2}-1}(1-u)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\,du$$
and the last integral can be computed through [Euler's beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), 
leading to:
$$\boxed{\, I(\alpha) = \color{red}{\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{\alpha+1}{2}\right)}}\, }$$
In particular, in the case $\alpha=1$ we have $I(1)=\frac{\pi}{2}$. For large values of $\alpha$ we have $I(\alpha)\approx\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2\alpha}}$.

Answer (score 3):

$\int _1^{\infty \:}\cfrac{1}{t\sqrt{t^2-1}}dt$

$\mathrm{Apply\:Integral\:Substitution:}\:\int f\left(g\left(x\right)\right)\cdot g^{'}\left(x\right)dx=\int f\left(u\right)du,\:\quad u=g\left(x\right)$
$u=t^2\quad \:du=2tdt$

$=\int \frac{1}{t\sqrt{u-1}}\frac{1}{2t}du$

$=\int \frac{1}{2u\sqrt{u-1}}du$

$=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{u\sqrt{u-1}}du$

$\mathrm{Apply\:Integral\:Substitution:}\:\int f\left(g\left(x\right)\right)\cdot g^{'}\left(x\right)dx=\int f\left(u\right)du,\:\quad u=g\left(x\right)$
$v=\sqrt{u-1}\quad \:dv=\frac{1}{2v}du$

$=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{2}{v^2+1}dv$

$\mathrm{Use\:the\:common\:integral}:\quad \int \:\frac{1}{v^2+1}dv=\arctan \left(v\right)$

$=\frac{1}{2}2\arctan \left(v\right)$

$\mathrm{Substitute\:back}\:v=\sqrt{u-1},\:u=t^2$

$=\frac{1}{2}2\arctan \left(\sqrt{t^2-1}\right)$

$=\arctan \left(\sqrt{t^2-1}\right)$

$Add\:a\:constant\:to\:the\:solution$

$=\arctan \left(\sqrt{t^2-1}\right)+C$

$\mathrm{Compute\:the\:boundaries}:\quad \int _1^{\infty \:}\frac{1}{t\sqrt{t^2-1}}dt=\frac{\pi }{2}-0$

$=\frac{\pi }{2}-0$

$=\frac{\pi }{2}$

Answer (score 2):

For the second equation, you can substitute $y=t^2$:
$$\int_1^{+\infty} \dfrac{1}{t^{\alpha}\sqrt{t^2 -1}} dt=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_1^{+\infty}\dfrac{y^{-(\alpha+1)/2}}{\sqrt{y-1}}dy$$

Using the Gamma function we get:
$$\dfrac{1}{2}\int_1^{+\infty}\dfrac{y^{-(\alpha+1)/2}}{\sqrt{y-1}}dy=\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{ \Gamma(\dfrac{\alpha}{2})\sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma(\dfrac{\alpha+1}{2})}$$

For $\alpha=1$, we get:
$$\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{ \Gamma(\dfrac{1}{2})\sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma(\dfrac{1+1}{2})}=\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}\sqrt{\pi}}{0!}=$$$$\dfrac{\pi}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $t=\sec(u)$:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_1^\infty\frac1{t\sqrt{t^2 -1}}\,\mathrm{d}t
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}1\,\mathrm{d}u\\[9pt]
&=\frac\pi2
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle\int \frac{1}{t\sqrt{t^2 -1}} dt=\sec^{-1}t+C\;$ for $t>0$, so

$\displaystyle\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{t\sqrt{t^2 -1}} dt=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2}}\;\;$ since $\displaystyle \lim_{t\to\infty}\sec^{-1}t=\frac{\pi}{2}\text{  and  }\lim_{t\to 1^{+}}\sec^{-1}t=0.$